# How to use ssh_config with matches for users

Tags: linux, openssh, private-key, identity-management

I'm trying to configure my ssh_config (CLIENT) to use different keyfiles depending on the user for the same host, but unable to make it work.
What is wrong?
It says bad arument

```
Host myServer
    Hostname myServer.net

Match #bad argument at this line
    Host myServer
    User jhon
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jhon

Match
    User foo
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo
```

----------------------->[SOLVED]<-----------------------

```
Host myServer
        Hostname myServer.net

Match user jhon host "myserver.net"
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jhon

Match user foo host "myserver.net"
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo


Host another
        User anyOtherOneUser
        Hostname another.net
        # any other configuration

Match user jhon host "another.net"
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jhon-another

Match user foo "another.net"
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo-another
```

Comment: The `Match` criteria need to be specified on the line starting with `Match`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Form the ssh man Page:

> Match
>   Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host or Match keyword) to be used only when the conditions following the Match keyword are satisfied. Match conditions are specified using one or more criteria or the single token all which always matches. The available criteria keywords are: canonical, final, exec, host, originalhost, user, and localuser. The all criteria must appear alone or immediately after canonical or final. Other criteria may be combined arbitrarily. All criteria but all, canonical, and final require an argument. Criteria may be negated by prepending an exclamation mark (‘!’).

You end the `Match` statement by using `Host`. Criterias are uncapitalised (e.g. use `host` instead of `Host`)

Comment: this does not work neither 
```
Host myServer
    Hostname myServer.net

Match user jhon host myServer
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jhon
```

Comment: What error message do you get now?